# get current gps location with Xamarin return 0

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, geolocation, gps

I try to get my current location on Android with Xamarin. I use a google Map and this following code :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace WorldHerp
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private double _latitude = 0.0;
        private double _longitude = 0.0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Task.Run(async () => { await GetCurrentLocationAsync(); });
            MapView.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(_latitude, _longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(1)).WithZoom(20));
        }

        private async Task GetCurrentLocationAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync();

                if (location != null)
                {
                    _latitude = location.Latitude;
                    _longitude = location.Longitude;
                }
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Faild", fnsEx.Message, "OK");
            }
            catch (PermissionException pEx)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Faild", pEx.Message, "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Faild", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

They just return 0 for my _latitude/_longitude variable. With a debug on my try {} it's like if he never go inside, but without show me any error.

Have you any idea?

Thanks per advance

Comment: The problem is the Task.Run is running Async so you are never waiting to get the location.  Remove the async.

Comment: But, this line is async, i obviously have async method:  
var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync();

Comment: It doesn't wait.  The async creates a separate process and then immediately goes to the MoveToRegion.

Comment: but GetLocationAsync want "await". How do you write the code so ?

Comment: Then use GetCurrentLocation() instead of GetCurrentLocationAsync()

Comment: doesn't exist ^^

Comment: You need the GetCurrentLocationAsync() but not the async.  See : GetCurrentLocationAsync()

Comment: @YannBtd Please check you Location Mode. When you set the Mode to `Device Only`, it would never go inside when debug. I test your code, when i set it to `High Accuracy` or `Battery Saving`, It works well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a async non empty method to await the result.

>

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace WorldHerp
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            var position = await GetCurrentLocationAsync();
            MapView.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius((position != null ? 
                                                             position : 
                                                             new Position(0.0, 0.0)), 
                                                             Distance.FromKilometers(1)).WithZoom(20));
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        private async Task<Xamarin.Essentials.Location> GetCurrentLocationAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                return await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync();
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Faild", fnsEx.Message, "OK");
            }
            catch (PermissionException pEx)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Faild", pEx.Message, "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Faild", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }
    }
}
```